# Drag to select items on NSOutlineView depending on mouse position

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

I'd like to create a basic `NSOutlineView` that mimics macOS Finder 'as List' behaviour. When clicking and dragging the `NSOutlineView` should either select rows or start a dragging session, depending on the starting position of the mouse.

- Drag selected row(s) -> **start a dragging session** for the selected rows
- Drag on the File Name part of a row -> **start a dragging session** for that row
- Drag anywhere right of the File Name (e.g. the empty part, or Date Modified column) -> **multi select rows**

[image]

I've noticed this behaviour in multiple applications - Finder (as List), ForkLift (as List), Nova (File Browser panel) - so I assume this is some standard behaviour for `NSOutlineView`.

But the default `NSOutlineView`, whether created in Interface Builder or programmatically, either always selects rows or always drags rows.

The `verticalMotionCanBeginDrag` property of `NSTableView` looks related, but is not enabling the above behaviour. When enabled a mouse drag will *always* start a dragging session. When disabled a vertical mouse drag will *always* select rows.

I've tried both view-based and cell-based `NSOutlineView`, both have the same dragging behaviour depending on `verticalMotionCanBeginDrag`.

A dragging session starts if items are returned from the following `NSOutlineViewDelegate` method:

```swift
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, pasteboardWriterForItem item: Any) -> NSPasteboardWriting? {
    // if nil is returned for all items, no dragging session will start
    // if an item is returned, a dragging session will start
}
```

But it feels strange to do logic in there, since it's called for all target row items.

Alternatively using the following `NSOutlineViewDelegate` method:

```swift
func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, writeItems items: [Any], to pasteboard: NSPasteboard) -> Bool {
   // determine starting point of drag?
}
```

But this has been deprecated since macOS 10.15.

How to determine whether a mouse drag will select rows or drag the items?

Comment: Method `canDragRows(with:at:)` of `NSTableView` sounds like what you need. There is no delegate method so you'll have to subclass `NSOutlineView`.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, thanks! I'm currently using the `pasteboardWriterForItem` delegate method with `NSApp.currentEvent` which seems to work fine, but `canDragRows` makes more sense. If you want to submit this as an answer I'll mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `NSOutlineView` and override

```
func canDragRows(with rowIndexes: IndexSet, at mouseDownPoint: NSPoint) -> Bool
```

It would be nice if there was a datasource method but there isn't.

Comment: Thanks again — appreciate all your answers on here!